# preg_match_all with named subpatterns

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I can`t figure out the following expression:

```
preg_match_all('/[(?P<slug>\w+\-)\-(?P<flag>(m|t))\-(?P<id>\d+)]+/', $slugs, $matches);
```

My $slugs variable is something like this:

```
article-slug-one-m-111617/article-slug-two-t-111611/article-slug-three-t-111581/article-slug-four-m-111609/
```

Comment: What is your question. what you want to do?

Comment: give us an example of what you want

Comment: Read the documentation chapter about [`PCRE` (Perl-compatible regular expressions)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) in the PHP manual. Everything is explained there on the [pattern syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression looks like an attempt to split up the path elements into slug, flag and id parts. It fails as the brackets `[ ... ]` is used to match characters but here it seems to be used to keep things together, like parentheses. It also fails to get the slug part right, as it does not allow for more than one series of word `\w` and dash `-` characters. I.e. that part matches 'article-' but not 'article-slug-one-'.

Maybe this is what you want?

```
$slugs = 'article-slug-one-m-111617/article-slug-two-t-111611/article-slug-three-t-111581/article-slug-four-m-111609/';

preg_match_all('/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)\-(?P<flag>[mt])\-(?P<id>\d+)/', $slugs, $matches);

echo "First slug : " . $matches['slug'][0], PHP_EOL;
echo "Second flag: " . $matches['flag'][1], PHP_EOL;
echo "Third ID   : " . $matches['id'][2], PHP_EOL;
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
First slug : article-slug-one
Second flag: t
Third ID   : 111581

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => article-slug-one-m-111617
            [1] => article-slug-two-t-111611
            [2] => article-slug-three-t-111581
            [3] => article-slug-four-m-111609
        )

    [slug] => Array
        (
            [0] => article-slug-one
            [1] => article-slug-two
            [2] => article-slug-three
            [3] => article-slug-four
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => article-slug-one
            [1] => article-slug-two
            [2] => article-slug-three
            [3] => article-slug-four
        )

    [flag] => Array
        (
            [0] => m
            [1] => t
            [2] => t
            [3] => m
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => m
            [1] => t
            [2] => t
            [3] => m
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111617
            [1] => 111611
            [2] => 111581
            [3] => 111609
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111617
            [1] => 111611
            [2] => 111581
            [3] => 111609
        )

)
```